# OpenShift - Credentials look-up for importing image

Tags: redis, openshift, docker-registry, redhat-containers

I am able to a launch an application with the Redis image from RedHat - `registry.redhat.io/rhel8/redis-5` using the following steps.

1. Create a service account at RedHat https://access.redhat.com/
2. Download the YAML (see below) for image pull secret once a token is created for that account.
3. Use the YAML file to create a secret.
4. Import the image.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: accoutNum-userName-pull-secret
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: token-value....long........string
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Add secret and import image:

```sh
oc create -f secret.yaml
oc import-image rhel8/redis-5 --from=registry.redhat.io/rhel8/redis-5 --confirm
```

The image meta data is imported:

```sh
oc get is
NAME      DOCKER REPO                       TAGS     UPDATED
redis-5   172.30.1.1:5000/project/redis-5   latest   About a minute ago
```

I am not clear how the import statement locates the secret to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenShift lookup automatically the authentication from type of `kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson` in the same namespace(project) if the registry is required authentication when pulling/push images. So if you need to access multiple external registry, then just create matched secret with the credential per registry.

I hope it help you, thanks.

Comment: Interestingly, the `oc new-app -i redis-5` doesn't seem to use credentials automatically. The `redis-5` is seen in the `oc get is` result.