# OpenShift - ErrImagePull even with PullSecret for rhel8/redis-5

Tags: redis, openshift, docker-image

I want to use [rhel8/redis-5 image](https://access.redhat.com/containers/#/registry.access.redhat.com/rhel8/redis-5). I have the RedHat service account, the registry token in OpenShift secret format. These are steps I am following to use the image.

```sh
oc create -f secret.yaml
oc import-image rhel8/redis-5 --from=registry.redhat.io/rhel8/redis-5 --confirm
oc new-app -i redis-5
```

The last step (`new-app`) keeps failing with a `Unauthorized 401` error. This is the event seen in the container that is to be spun up as a result of `new-app`.

```sh
Failed to pull image "registry.redhat.io/rhel8/redis-5@sha256:361f32130a48861ff41783b38f328fde0df14b44c50ae12a212947285c6710c2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unable to retrieve auth token: 401 unauthorized
```

I am not sure, how I should provide the image pull secret, [if at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58485415/919480). Can you please help me get the image running?

Comment: Looks like the `oc new-app -i redis-5` is trying pull the image into the registry again. You should use the image that was just imported.

Comment: The `redis-5` image is visible in `oc get is`. Hence, the `new-app redis-5`. How do we use the image that was just imported? BTW, as per the help text of `import-image`, only meta data is imported.

Comment: @Rinor how do we do that? I didn't follow.

Also, please note that, I am facing the same issue with web console too.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the full url and assumed the problem is with the local registry.